# referencing main subequation

Tags: hyperref, labels

In the following example i labeled each subeqnation.

```
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{gather}
    R_0 = 0 \label{subeqn:ini-cond-r}  \\
    N_0 = 0 \label{subeqn:ini-cond-n}
  \end{gather}
\end{subequations}
```

then i could give as reference each equation separately.

What i would like to have, assuming the subequation numbers are *1.1a* and *1.1b*, is a reference to *1.1* or somehow that LaTeX will show the number *1.1* (It would be nice a solution with hyperref, since i already use it in my work)

Answer (score 15):

You can set an extra label inside the environment `subequations` but outside the inner math environment. So you will get reference to the parent counter.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
\begin{equation}
A_0=1
\end{equation}

\begin{subequations}
  \label{foo}
  \begin{gather}
    R_0 = 0 \label{subeqn:ini-cond-r}  \\
    N_0 = 0 \label{subeqn:ini-cond-n}
  \end{gather}
\end{subequations}

\begin{equation}
A_0=1
\end{equation}

\eqref{subeqn:ini-cond-r} and \eqref{subeqn:ini-cond-n} and \eqref{foo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This method does not work if I want to reference only the main equation without ever referencing sub equations when using `hyperref` package.

Comment: Worked fine to me without referencing the main equation.

Answer (score 4):

You can put another label to `subequations` environment.

```
\begin{subequations}\label{refertothis}
  \begin{gather}
    R_0 = 0 \label{subeqn:ini-cond-r}  \\
    N_0 = 0 \label{subeqn:ini-cond-n}
  \end{gather}
\end{subequations}
```

Then, you can refer to the equation set via `\eqref{refertothis}`.

Comment: This method does not work if I want to reference only the main equation without ever referencing sub equations when using `hyperref` package.

Comment: @Vlad What do you mean by hyperref package? Did you try `\eqref{refertothis}` ?